# [SQL][DB2] Returns 0 when no records

Tags: sql, date, join, db2, recursive-query

The following query returns the number of transactions per month.
I would like the query to return 0 in the month when there were no transactions in the TV_TRANSACTION table (no records).

```
WITH
msc (num) AS
(VALUES (TIMESTAMP('2019-10-01 00:00:00.001'))
UNION ALL
SELECT num + 1 MONTH
FROM msc
WHERE num < current timestamp - 1 MONTH
)
SELECT SUBSTR(CHAR(num),1,7), 
count(case when t.STATUS = 44 and t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0 then 1 else 0 end) FROM TV_TRANSACTION t
join TB_INSTALLATION i on t.INSTALLATION_ID = i.INSTALLATION_ID
right join msc mc on SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) = SUBSTR(CHAR(mc.num),1,7)
where i.IB24_VERSION = 2
and date(t.REGISTRATION_DATE) >= '2019-10-01'
and t.STATUS = 44
and t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0
and SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) >= SUBSTR(CHAR(i.IB24_VERSION_UPDATE_DATE),1,7)
group by SUBSTR(CHAR(mc.num),1,7)
```

At the moment the query returns the result

```
2020-02 | 1552
2020-03 | 6981
2020-04 | 16439
2020-05 | 5
```

How to modify a query to get something like this?:

```
2019-10 | 0
2019-11 | 0
2019-12 | 0
2020-01 | 0    
2020-02 | 1552
2020-03 | 6981
2020-04 | 16439
2020-05 | 5
```

Comment: You need to start with a list of months somehow; perhaps from a calendar table.

Comment: The `RIGHT JOIN` gets automatically converted into an `INNER JOIN` since your `WHERE` clause includes columns from the left table. That's the issue. Solution: **Change `WHERE` to `AND`**.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, msc table return list of months

Comment: Did you change `WHERE` to `AND`?

Answer (score 1):

Start the joins from the `CTE` and use `LEFT` joins for the other tables, including all the conditions in the ON clauses and not the WHERE clause:

```
WITH msc(num) AS (
  VALUES (TIMESTAMP('2019-10-01 00:00:00.001'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + 1 MONTH
  FROM msc
  WHERE num < current timestamp - 1 MONTH
)
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(CHAR(num),1,7), 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.STATUS = 44 AND t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0 THEN 1 END) 
FROM msc mc
LEFT JOIN TV_TRANSACTION t 
ON    SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) = SUBSTR(CHAR(mc.num),1,7)
  AND date(t.REGISTRATION_DATE) >= '2019-10-01'
  AND t.STATUS = 44
  AND t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0
LEFT JOIN TB_INSTALLATION i 
ON    t.INSTALLATION_ID = i.INSTALLATION_ID
  AND i.IB24_VERSION = 2
  AND SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) >= SUBSTR(CHAR(i.IB24_VERSION_UPDATE_DATE),1,7)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CHAR(mc.num),1,7)
```

Also I removed the `ELSE` part from the `CASE` expression of `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 1):

It has been commented already that you  need to put the conditions in the join rather than in the `where` clause. Also, the logic is much simpler if you start from the dates table, and then bring the additional tables with `left join`s.

As far as I see, other optimizations of fixes are  possible:

- you can use dates rather than timestamps in the cte
- filtering using half-open intervals is more efficient than using string functions (this makes these predicates SARGeable, meaning that they can take advantage of an index)
- there is no need for the conditional logic in the `count()`, since it matches the join conditions already
- `count()` takes in account `0` (it ignores `null` values only)- presumably, you just want to count how many records are available in both tables for each date, so counting anything from the second `left join` is enough
- I renamed the cte to something that makes more sense to me

This should be (close enough to) what you want:

```
with all_dates (dt) as
    (values (date('2019-10-01''))
    union all
    select num + 1 month from msc where num < current timestamp 
)
select 
    d.dt,
    count(i.installation_id) no_matches 
from  all_dates d
left join tv_transaction t
    on  t.registration_date >= d.dt
    and t.registration_date < d.dt + 1 day
    and t.status = 44
    and t.transaction_type = 0
left join tb_installation i 
    on  i.installation_id = t.installation_id
    and i.ib24_version = 2
    and i.ib24_version_update_date <= d.dt
group by d.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I've modified the query below and it looks like it works

```
WITH
msc (num) AS
(VALUES (TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 00:00:00.001'))
UNION ALL
SELECT num + 1 MONTH
FROM msc
WHERE num < current timestamp - 1 MONTH
)
SELECT substr(char(mc.num),1,7), 
count(case when t.STATUS = 44 and t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0 then 1 end) FROM TV_TRANSACTION t
join TB_INSTALLATION i on t.INSTALLATION_ID = i.INSTALLATION_ID and i.IB24_VERSION = 2
right join msc mc on SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) = substr(char(mc.num),1,7) and date(t.REGISTRATION_DATE) >= '2019-10-01' and t.STATUS = 44 and t.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 0
and SUBSTR(CHAR(t.REGISTRATION_DATE),1,7) >= SUBSTR(CHAR(i.IB24_VERSION_UPDATE_DATE),1,7)
group by substr(char(mc.num),1,7)
```

Comment: Although right joins are never used (it's always easier to visualize the concept of a left join), your code would work if you change the join of TV_TRANSACTION to TB_INSTALLATION to a RIGHT join also.